# e4 selectionservice - list or single object and adapters

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I have a question regarding "best practice" on the e4 selectionservice

1) Handling single and multiple selection

E.g on a tableviewer I can select a single or multiple elements. Depending on that, my active selection is either a object or a collection of objects.

What is the best practice to handle that in my listener?

....selectionService.setSelection(structuredSelection.getFirstElement())

OR

....selectionService.setSelection(structuredSelection.asList())

public void xy (@Optional @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) 
List selection){} --> selection is null if a single element is selected

OR

public void xyz (@Optional @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) MyObject selection){} --> selection is null if multiple elements are selected

Do I need to implement both methods to handle both scenarios? Why is a single element not packed in a list or vice versa?

2)
How to handle active selections that can be adapted to a target Object?
Do I need to have ISelection parameter and check for the adaptation manually or is there any way the framework can adapt and inject if possible?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: In the context of the Eclipse e4 selection service this is a perfectly reasonable question and is not too broad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The normal selection is the actual `IStructuredSelection` object, **not** its contents:

```java
selectionService.setSelection(structuredSelection);


public void xx(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) IStructuredSelection selection)
```

So you only have one method and it receives all types of selection.

For adaptable objects there is nothing that will do this automatically. Use the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Adapters` class to adapt an object:

```java
IFile file = Adapters.adapt(object, IFile.class);
```